# Is there a polynomial $f \in Q[x]$ such that $f(x) = 1 \pmod {x^2+1}$ and $f(x) = x \pmod {x^{100}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a polynomial $f \in Q[x]$ such that $f(x) = 1 \pmod {x^2+1}$ and $f(x) = x \pmod {x^{100}}$ Considered the Chinese Remainder theorem, but $(x^2+1)$ is not coprime to $(x^{100})$. How to locate a concrete example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but $x^2+1$ is not coprime to $x^{100}$

Yes, it is. Evaluate $x^{100}$ at a zero of $x^2+1$ - either of them, both of which are fourth roots of unity - and we get $1$.

So, then, $x^{100}\equiv 1\mod x^2+1$. From that, $x+x^{100}(1-x)=x+x^{100}-x^{101}$ is equivalent to $x$ mod $x^{100}$ and equivalent to $x+1-x=1$ mod $x^2+1$.

Comment: we only know $x^2+1|x^{100}-1$ in $\mathbb C[x]$, but how do you know it is also true in $Q[x]$?

Comment: Evaluating at roots? That only works where they exist. But, from that, we  find the factorization $x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)$ and $x^4\equiv 1\mod x^2+1$, which works anywhere.